# Explain how the AF flag works in an x86 instructions?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-16

I have a little 8086 emulator and I've had a long standing bug for like 2 years now that AF does not behave properly inside of sub and add instructions.

My current way of computing its value is this for 8 bit numbers and subtraction:

```
uint8_t base=... , subt=...
base=base&0xF;
subt=subt&0xF; //isolate bottom nibble
if((int16_t)base-subt>7 || (int16_t)base-subt<-7){
    flags.af=1;
}else{
   flags.af=0;
}
```

(assuming an instruction like `sub base,subt` )

And for adding it's like this:

```
uint8_t base=... , adder=...
base=base&0xF;
adder=adder&0xF; //isolate bottom nibble
if(base+adder>7 || base+adder<-7){
    flags.af=1;
}else{
   flags.af=0;
}
```

(for an instruction like `add base,adder`)

How do I properly calculate the AF flag in my emulator for such instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
flags.af = (((base-subt) & ~0xf) != 0);
```

Checks to see if the upper bits are anything except zero, which would indicate an overflow or underflow out of the bottom 4 bits.

Here's a version that's a little closer to your original. Note that the difference between two 4-bit quantities will never be greater than 15. Likewise the addition will never be less than 0.

```
flags.af = ((int16_t)base-subt < -15);

flags.af = ((int16_t)base+adder > 15);
```

Putting parentheses around a boolean expression is just a style preference of mine, I know they're redundant.

Comment: I can see how the bitwise version is equivalent to the other versions. If only I had known about stack overflow when I first was writing this emulator! 7 lines of code into 1.

Comment: @Earlz, I left out the lines where you were `&0xf`, those are still necessary in this version. You can easily put them into the expression though and still end up with a one-liner.